# Result set not returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to ensure this always returns a result set even if no data in present ?

Now if `#TMP_SUMMARY1` return no rows .

How can I ensure this below query returns me a table with no rows and not just show me this Messages tab with this message below and no results tab.

> (0 row(s) affected)

This not returning a result set in this circumstance is causing me a nightmare !

```
IF (@SUMMARY = 'Agent Summary')

BEGIN


DECLARE @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colSum1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query1  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Agent) 
                    from #TMP_SUMMARY1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
print @cols1

select @colSum1 = STUFF((SELECT distinct ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(Agent)+') as ' +QUOTENAME(Agent)
                    from #TMP_SUMMARY1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

print @colSum1 

set @query1 = 'select 
                case when [PAYMENT TYPE] is null then ''*GRAND TOTAL'' else [Credit/Debit] end [Credit/Debit],
                case when [PAYMENT TYPE] is null then '''' else [PAYMENT TYPE] end [PAYMENT TYPE],
                '+@colSum1 +'
              from
              (
                select  [Agent] , 
                  [Credit/Debit], 
                  [PAYMENT TYPE], 
                  value
                from #TMP_SUMMARY2
                unpivot
                (
                  value
                  for [Credit/Debit] in ([Amount Credit], [Amount Debit])

                ) unpiv
              ) src
              pivot
              (
                sum(value)
                for agent in ('+@cols1+')
              ) piv
              group by GROUPING SETS ([Credit/Debit], [PAYMENT TYPE]), ([Credit/Debit])'

execute(@query1)  

END
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question (so I'm leaving it here as a comment), but you should really consider using `sp_executesql` rather than `EXECUTE`, so that you have protection against SQL Injection within your dynamic SQL Query.
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#sp_executesql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no rows in #TMP_SUMMARY1, then the values of @cols1 and @colsum1 will be null and your dynamic sql will have invalid syntax.  Why not just wrap your dynamic sql with an

```
If (@cols1 is not null)
```

and don't execute the statement when there are no columns.